# Vedavati and Vaishno Devi question

Tags: scripture, ramayana

Questions about Vedavati and Vaishno Devi?

A) Is Vedavati mentioned in the Valmiki/original Ramayan? Not in Uttar Kanda but his original work which ends after the return to Ayodhya.

B) Is her story in Vishnu Puran or Bhagavat Puran?

Seems like a lot of legends are added on to her so was curious.

C) Is Vaishno Devi in any of the scriptures?
D) Where is the story of her meeting Shri Ram and marrying the Kalai avatars from? Isn’t she a representation of all the Tridevis so how can she marry Vishnu??

Comment: You can separate the Vaishno Devi and Vedavati questions into two

Answer (score 1):

Ravana mentions Vedavati in Yuddha Kanda -

*"Further, I was formerly cursed by Vedavati when she was humiliated by me. The same Vedavati is born as the highly fortunate Seetha the daughter of Janaka."*

https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga60/yuddha_60_frame.htm